# Should [goal] be kept?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [goal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/goal) tag seems useless to me. Some questions are about Google Analytics, others are about goals in Maven and others are about path finding.

Should this tag be kept, or can it be burninated?

Comment: Why the downvotes? ProgramFOX's analysis seems correct to me after a 10-second glance; if there's something you can see that he's missed, you should point it out instead of silently downvoting and leaving others to wonder why. The only objection I can think of is that while the tag is being used to mean a handful of different things, it *does* add some information, so maybe it would be better to split it into, say, `google-analytics-goal` and `maven-goal` instead of simply burninating.

Comment: Possible reasons for downvotes: (1) thinking this is a useful tag, (2) thinking this question is not useful, (3) thinking this question is not well-presented, (4) finding the evidence included to be lacking or otherwise uncompelling, (5) "burnination" fatigue, (6) dog just got bitten by a rattlesnake, etc.

Comment: Here's a question: why can't the other tags on the question serve to disambiguate this one? The questions do seem to be *about* `[goal]`, so the tag doesn't appear to be incorrect or useless. Why do we need `[google-analytics-goal]` when we already have a `[google-analytics]` tag?

Comment: @Cody Gray Because [meta tags are bad.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

Comment: The world cup is going on and you want to burn the `goal` tag?

Comment: @bamboon You can get rid of `goal` tag during world cup... just not `gooooooooooooooooooaaaallll` tag.